# What is true meaning of the White Walkers' terrifying Spiral Symbol in GOT

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the season 8 episode, we saw the following symbol

[image]

His victims in this episode were the residents of Last Hearth—the seat of House Umber, a Northern ally of House Stark. None of them were left in the Northern fortress except for the young Lord Ned Umber, dead and nailed to the wall amidst a slew of severed limbs in a spiral pattern.

Tormund and their crew find the haunting symbol when they arrive at Last Hearth. "**It's a message from the Night King**," Beric notes of the bloody formation. But what is the Night King saying?

We have seen the same kind of symbol in Season 1, Episode 1. So what is the meaning behind those symbols?

Comment: A video blogger suggested it is representative of stupid fan theories swirling down the toilet every week.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - that's ridiculous - Westeros is in the Northern Hemisphere so their toilets swirl clockwise, not counter-clockwise.